# Privacy in Google Assistant

Tags: privacy, google-now, google-assistant

The other day my phone upgraded from Google Now to Google Assistant. I was having a conversation with a coworker and noticed my phone vibrate. Google Assistant had recorded the conversation and tried to answer a question even though I never said "ok google".

My phone was in standby and in my pocket and I'm not ok with this. Is there a way to set it so I must launch an app to cause it to start listening, like some sort of widget? Is Google Assistant only supposed to record when you say "Ok Google" or does it not need any specific phrase? Does Google Now offer better privacy than Google Assistant? If not, is there a way to remove them both?

Answer (score 1):

In very noisy situation Assistant may be invoked by mistake. If you do not want to happen this again then turn off OK Google Detection from any screen in the Google settings.